# Timed Banner Greeting In Kivy

Tags: python, time, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to build a banner that will be displayed on a button in Kivy that in the morning says "Good Morning", in the afternoon "Good Afternoon", and in the evening "Good Evening". I am having trouble solving this. So far, this is what I have for my code:

In the .py file:

```
    class Personal_Assistant(BoxLayout):

        time_stamp = 0
        morning = 'Good Morning'
        afternoon = 'Good Afternoon'
        evening = 'Good even'
        name = 'James'
        def timer(self):
           self.now = datetime.datetime.now()
           if self.now > 5 and self.now <12:
                return self.morning, 'James'
           elif self.now > 12 and self.now < 5:
               return self.afternoon, 'James'

          elif self.now > 5 and self.now < 12:
                return self.evening, 'James'
```

In the .kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20
    spacing: 40
    Button:

        text: root.timer()
        color: (255, 255, 255, 255)
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: 40
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'middle'
        background_color: (0, 0, 255, 0.6)
```

Comment: I am not sure how to get the current time in hours, but I have tried using if statements that depend on the hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the **hour** attribute

```
self.now = datetime.datetime.now().hour
```